# Search by json key in jsonb column PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with following structure (simplified):

**Sometable:**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"data": [{"type": {"code": "S"}}, {"type": {"code": "aB"}}]}` |
| 2 | `{"data": [{"type": {"code": "B"}}]}` |

'Data' is jsonb type, json structure is always the same. I need to find all records where 'code equals certain value, for example 'B'.

I've tried:

```
select * from sometable t 
where 'B' in (jsonb_array_elements((t.data->'data'))#>>'{type, code}');
```

But that gives me an error:

> set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE.

Basically, anything I've tried in 'where' with 'jsonb_array_elements' gives that error. Is there any other way to find records by value of the 'code' key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@>` operator

```
select * 
from sometable t 
where (t.data -> 'data') @> '[{"type": {"code": "B"}}]'
```

or

```
select * 
from sometable t 
where t.data  @> '{"data": [{"type": {"code": "B"}}]}'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a5cd16c293942d7f0c1a9f52c4e3493e)

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: @SergeiTonoian: sorry, there was a typo. See my edit