# How to read a json inside a column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called metadata that is a json with one of the keys called "state", I need to select all the registries with a state="OK" inside the metadata.

How could I do this?

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442003/search-by-json-key-in-jsonb-column-postgresql)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html